# Stack Overflow after too many non-recursive Method Calls

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I'm currently writing a console program that's split into many different tasks/methods.
It roughly goes like this:

```
static void method1() {
    //do something
    method2();
}

static void method2() {
    //do something
    method3();
}
```

......

```
static void methodN() {
    //doesn't get executed because there's a StackOverflow
}
```

My question is, does this lead to a StackOverflow eventually? There is no recursion and no infinite loop, just that every method runs the next method at the end to keep the program going.

If this is the reason why I get a StackOverflow, what can I change to prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question explains call stack limit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832311/call-stack-limitation-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep calling methods like that, there *will* eventually be a stack overflow. Exactly when depends on how big your stack is. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29832372/5133585), it's 1MB.

To avoid stack overflows, have the methods *return* before calling the next one. According to what you said, you have divided up your program into methods:

```
static void Method1() { ... }
static void Method2() { ... }
static void Method3() { ... }
static void Method4() { ... }
```

Instead of calling `method2` from inside `method1` and calling `method3` from inside `method2`, you can call all these methods sequentially in your `Main` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Method1();
    Method2();
    Method3();
    Method4();
}
```

This way you won't fill up the stack.

Just for fun, I wrote this little piece of code to find out when will Stack Overflow occur:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Method(1, 1);
}

static void Method(int x, int y) {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Method(x + 1, y + 1);
}
```

For me, it shows `173897` before saying a stack overflow occurred.

Comment: It was right there in front of me and i didn't see it... Calling them all within another method instead of them calling themselves. Thank you very much! I honestly did not think i'd get an answer this quick.

Comment: @Yiasmat Stack Overflow's traffic is _huge_. thousands of answers being posted and millions of page views per day. It is normal to get an answer quickly.

Comment: As an addition: Those method calls were actually not my problem. I figured out that i called LevelManager.LoadHub(1) in LoadHub instead of LevelManager.LoadHub1() so it actually was an infinite loop. I still changed it so that methods don't call the next one. Again: thanks for the answers @everyone